# How do I iterate through registry keys using C#?

Tags: c#, registry

how can iterate through the registry using C#? I wish to create a structure for representing attributes of each key.

Comment: This will break any portability with Mono on other systems besides Windows. Just a warning.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you need is `GetSubKeyNames()` as in this example.

```
private void GetSubKeys(RegistryKey SubKey)
{
    foreach(string sub in SubKey.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
      MessageBox.Show(sub);
      RegistryKey local = Registry.Users;
      local = SubKey.OpenSubKey(sub,true);
      GetSubKeys(local); // By recalling itself it makes sure it get all the subkey names
    }
}

//This is how we call the recursive function GetSubKeys
RegistryKey OurKey = Registry.Users;
OurKey = OurKey.OpenSubKey(@".DEFAULT\test",true);
GetSubKeys(OurKey);
```

(NOTE: This was original copied from a tutorial http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/registry-ins-and-outs-using-c/, but the site now appears to be down).

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was just about to write arecursive function but im not familiar with the methods!

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
private void  GetSubKeys(RegistryKey SubKey)
{
    foreach(string sub in SubKey.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
      MessageBox.Show(sub);
      RegistryKey local = Registry.Users;
      local = SubKey.OpenSubKey(sub,true);
      GetSubKeys(local); // By recalling itselfit makes sure it get all the subkey names
    }
}
//This is how we call the recursive function GetSubKeys
RegistryKey OurKey = Registry.Users;
OurKey = OurKey.OpenSubKey(@".DEFAULT\test",true);
GetSubKeys(OurKey);
```

http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/registry-ins-and-outs-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames) method.

This function will retrieve the name of all subkeys and you can iterate through them and do whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` and the `GetSubKeyNames` method as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Be aware though that this might be very slow if you're iterating through a large part of the registry.